# Place a word in a 2d array

Tags: java, arrays, algorithm

is there a way to place a word in a 2d array in a specific position? For example,i want to give the word, choose vertical or horizontal and the position ((3,3) or (3,4) or (5,6) etc) and the word will be placed in that position.This is my code for the array...

```
char [][] Board = new char [16][16];


    for (int i = 1; i<Board.length; i++) {
        if (i != 1) {
            System.out.println("\t");
            System.out.print(i-1);
        }

        for (int j = 1; j <Board.length; j++) {
            if ((j == 8 && i == 8) ||(j ==9 && i == 9) ||(j == 10 && i == 10) ||(j == 2        && i == 2) )
            {
                Board[i][j] = '*';
                System.out.print(Board[i][j]);
            }
            else {
                if (i == 1) {
                    System.out.print("\t");
                    System.out.print(j-1);
                }
                else {
                   Board[i][j] = '_';
                    System.out.print("\t");
                    System.out.print(""+Board[i][j]);
}

}
```

(the * means that the word cant be placed there)

Comment: i did this "char *[][] Board = new char [16][16];" and got the message "not a statement.can not find symbol:Board"....Should i do something else?

Comment: Oh, do you mean you want to specify a starting index and orientation, such that if I say placeWord("foo", 3, 4, HORIZONTAL), you would end up with board[3][4] = 'f', board[3][5] = 'o', etc.?

Comment: yes this is exactly what i want

Comment: Argh, wait, this is Java? I thought this was C++. Forget it. In fact, you should declare a `String[][]`!

Comment: When i do this "String[][]" and place a word all then letters of the word are placed in the same position(e.g (2,3) ).i want the first letter to be placed in (2,3) the second in (2,4) etc....:/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is there a way to place a word in a 2d array in a specific position?

Yes you can implement that.  The pseudo-code is something like this:

```
public void placeWordHorizontally(char[][] board, String word, int x, int y) {
    for (int i = 0; i < word.length(); i++) {
        if (y + i >= board[x].length) {
             // fail ... edge of board
        } else if (board[x][y + i]) == '*') {
             // fail ... blocked.
        } else {
             board[x][y + i] = word.charAt(i);
        }
    }
}
```

and to do the vertical case you add `i` etcetera to the `x` position.

I won't give you the exact code because you'll learn more if you fill in the details yourself.

Comment: thanks Stephen for your response..i am working on your code even though it is a litte bit hard as i am new in java..any other help is welcome...:)

Comment: If you don't tell us why you can't make it work, we can't help you.

Comment: in main i create the board as i wrote in my fisrt post,i create a class which contains the public void placeWordHorizontally that you wrote...then i put values in main to test it (these are the values  "String s="abc";
   int k=2;
   int m=3;
b.placeWordHorizontally(Board, s, m, m);
System.out.println(Arrays.deepToString(Board));" and it returns two arrays--the fisrt is the one with the stars-and the second is an empty one with the values i put...i am confused

Comment: i also tried this to print the board for(int i=0;i<Board.length;i++)
{
System.out.println(Board[i]);
} but it returns a similar thing like the last one

Comment: Try running your code with a debugger to see what it is doing.  I hope you noticed that the code that I wrote was incomplete and buggy.